# AnchorTabString Not Functioning Correctly

Tags: docusignapi

I have an application that uses unique AnchorTabStrings for locating signature blocks. When we tested the application using the DocuSign Sandbox the signing locations worked flawlessly. However, now in production we are experiencing erroneous behavior. Sometimes the location of the signature is completely off (meaning that it appears in a random location in the document) and other times the signature block is completely omitted (not used). The application is a Windows C# MVVM WPF Desktop application and we are using the DocuSign SOAP API. The number of signature blocks varies depending on how many pages are produced by the user in the application. The names of the AnchorTabStrings I'm using are "AuditorSignatureBlock", "OwnerManagerSignatureBlock", and "TechnicianSignatureBlock". We are not using document templates. Here's a snippet of code where we create a new signing tab within the document.

```
new Tab
{
    DocumentID = this.dataContext._inspReport.DocumentGuid.ToString(),
    RecipientID = idRoutingNumber.ToString(),
    Type = TabTypeCode.SignHere,
    AnchorTabItem = new AnchorTab
    {
        AnchorTabString = "AuditorSignatureBlock",
        XOffset = 0,
        YOffset = 0
    }
}
```

Update:
I have narrowed the issue down to the number of pages. Meaning when there is 3 or more pages within the envelope, this is when the feature no longer functions. I produced the same document in the DocuSign sandbox environment and this issue is not apparent. I have submitted a case with DocuSign support.

Answer (score 0):

Since your app is working on the developer sandbox system (demo), but not on the production system, the document may different or anchor string placement may not be enabled on your production account (see below).

First try with the exact same document that worked on the developer sandbox system. If that works but the new document does not, then check carefully that the anchor string in the new document does not include any spaces or other white space, and that it is not being wrapped across two lines.

For example, you can make a test document where the anchor text is *not* white, then, once it works, change the text color to white.

I've had cases where the transformation from the document creation system to PDF introduced unexpected changes.

For these reasons, one common technique is use strings such as /auditsig1/ for the anchors.

Another diagnostic technique to try is to create an anchor field (tab) by using the DocuSign web tool, and then check that DocuSign can locate the anchor text in your document. In other words, try it on production without your application at all.

**Re: anchor strings an optional feature**

Yes, anchor strings (also know as Auto-place) may not be enabled for your production account. To check, use the DocuSign web tool as described above. If anchor strings are not enabled there then contact DocuSign to have the feature added to your account.

Answer (score 0):

What happened had nothing to do with AnchorTabStrings. In production there was an additional recipient added for carbon copy and I did not properly handle the recipient IDs (had two recipients with the same ID). Sorry, my fault :(